# How do I iterate through a df column (where each row is a list), looking for elements in a different list?

Tags: python, pandas

I would love your advice on the best code to complete the following task:

```
menu_items = ['acres',
 'adobo',
 'affogato',
 'agua',
 'aioli',
 'akaushi',
 'alaskan',
 'almonds',
 'ambriza',
 'american',
 'angolotti',
 'antiguas',
 'apple',
 'apples',
 'arancini',
 'arroz',
 'artichoke',
 'arugula',
 'asada',
 'asado',
 'asparagus',
 'atlantic',
 'avocado',
 'avokatsu',
 'award',
 'baby',
 'back',
 'backyard',
 'bacon',
 'baked',
 'bakes',
 'balls',
 'balsalmic',
 'tomato']

df['lemmatized'] = [['beautiful', 'location', 'steak', 'seafood', 'par', 'expectation', 'restaurant', 'caliber', 'saute', 'spinach', 'amazing', 'service', 'however', 'well', 'average', 'expectation', 'high', 'end', 'restaurant', 'sticking', 'eddie', 'v', 'trulucks', 'future'],['almonds','pleasant', 'surprise', 'came', 'last', 'week', 'storm', 'tired', 'crabby', 'air', 'travel', 'food', 'breath', 'fresh', 'air', 'area', 'saturated', 'nothing', 'special', 'run', 'mill', 'tex', 'mex', 'ambriza', 'waitress', 'exceptional', 'blew', 'u', 'away', 'said', 'th', 'table', 'ever', 'new', 'server', 'super', 'friendly', 'get', 'anymore', 'looking', 'forward', 'digging', 'menu', 'fun'],['ordered', 'corn', 'cob', 'really', 'good', 'fact', 'served', 'basil', 'sauce', 'added', 'different', 'taste', 'altogether', 'corn', 'juicy', 'well', 'smoked', 'offer', 'pizza', 'hand', 'tossed', 'took', 'arrive', 'would', 'say', 'min', 'tomato', 'basil', 'okay']]
```

I have a variable called `menu_items` which is a single-word list of menu item names.

[image]

Next, in a dataframe I have a column of reviews where each row is one review and each review is broken down into a list of single words.

[image]

What I am trying to do is add code that will iterate through the `lemmatized` column and search each word in each list for the presence of any words found in the `menu_items` list.

If a word is found in the review single word list that matches a word in the `menu_items` list I want to display the number of matches in a column called `df['Match'].`

Here is what I have tried:

```
for item in df['lemmatized']:
    for element in item:
        if element in menu_items:
            df['Match'] += 1
        else:
           df['Match'] = 0
```

This produced zero matches even though I have visually confirmed that there are matches.

Comment: Will you please share your data as text, so I can copy/paste? Thank you :)

Comment: Are the values in your "lemmatized" column actually strings? Or are they lists of strings? It's not possible to tell by inspection unfortunately. You need to drill down and inspect the type, e.g.: `type(df["lemmatized"][0])`.

Comment: Your code has different issues:
1. It reset the df['Match'] counter each time an item is NOT in the list
2. In setting df['Match']  = 0 (or += 1), you are not setting the counter for each row, but you are assign an integer to a DataFrame column, which is wrong

Comment: Did you see my answer, @Brionne? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to use set intersection (assuming you're trying to count *unique* matches, i.e., you're not interested in how many times "apple" is mentioned in a review, only that it is mentioned, period).

This *should* get you what you want, again, **assuming you want to count unique matches** and assuming your `lemmatized` column values are indeed lists of strings:

```py
df["lemmatized"].apply(lambda r: len(set(r) & set(menu_items)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `explode` and `groupby` with `level=0` (which does count duplicates):

```
df['matches'] = df['lemmatized'].explode().isin(menu_items).groupby(level=0).sum()
```